# Button input type submit not submitting in React with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I added the React.js context cause of the NavLink reference (from React Router) in the button I am trying to use. Either way, when I want to submit data with:

```
submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Submitted");
}
```

This will work:

```
<FormGroup>
  <input type="submit" />
</FormGroup>
```

But this will not:

```
<FormGroup>
    <Button type="submit" id="submitButton" color="primary"><NavLink to="/Confirm">Submit</NavLink></Button>
</FormGroup>
```

Not sure why the second won't work, but it is my preferred method. Any ideas or thoughts as to why? I know `<button>` is newer, but adding `type="input"` should force it ton work all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NavLink` component is already listening to it's own submit/click event, which isn't propagating to your own form's onSubmit.

The easy solution would simply to bind the `NavLink`'s onClick to your own handler:

```
<FormGroup>
    <Button type="submit" id="submitButton" color="primary">
        <NavLink to="/Confirm" onClick={this.submitData.bind(this)}>Submit</NavLink>
    </Button>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not let the `<NavLink>` redirect afterwards. Almost like if the form submits, it just stops, then does not redirect to a confirmation page.

Comment: Remove the `event.preventDefault()`.